# how to catch an exception inside a scala future' s callback onCompelete Success case?

Tags: concurrency, akka, future, akka-actor

I have a future and sending that value to the caller actor my problem is I am calling future.onCompelete and inside its case Success callback I am getting an exception I want to know what is the right way to catch that exception as the Failure block will not work in this use case
here is my code

```
val future = Futute{calling a http route which sends back a response}
future.onComplete {
case Success (response) => //do some processing with response got some exception while doing this 
throw new RunTimeException("got exception while working the response")
sender() ! response
case Failure (ex) =>  ex.printStackTrace
}
```

in the above code, I am unable to catch the exception I only got AskTimeOutException when i am calling this future code
I can only catch the exception if I surround it with try-catch
like this

```
val future = Futute{calling a http route which sends back a response}
    future.onComplete {
    case Success (response) => //do some processing with response got some exception while doing this 
try {    
throw new RunTimeException("got exception while working the response")
    sender() ! response
    }
    catch {
     case ex:Exception(e)=>log.error("got an exception",ex)
     }
case Failure (ex) =>  ex.printStackTrace
    }
```

is this the right approach to do this? or is there any better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

In general, `onComplete` shouldn't be used if you care about an exception thrown in the callback (nor should the other `Unit`-returning method which needs an (implicit) `ExecutionContext`: `foreach`).

The most general approach and the most similar to `onComplete` is to use `transform` (or its cousin `transformWith`: `transform` is to `transformWith` as `map` is to `flatMap`), for example

```scala
future.transform {
  case Success(response) =>
    // these are both equivalent... the exception will get wrapped into a failed future
    Failure(new RuntimeException("BOOM!"))
    throw new RuntimeException("BOOM!")

  case f @ Failure(ex) =>
    ex.printStackTrace()
    f  // pass-through
}
```